# Customized item sets doesn't appear in game

Tags: league-of-legends

I have a bunch of item sets I created . They are all champion specific but are configured to work on all maps . Problem is I don't have this sub menu ingame which lets me alternate between default recommended and my item list .

even after I made the list available for all champs ... it doesn't show up .

Comment: Where are you looking?

Comment: the recommended tab where there should be a drop down menu to choose my custom set .

Comment: is it set to only one map?

Comment: nope all maps ... only each set is set to 1 champion

Comment: were the sets made on a different computer? they are pc specific, they are not stored on the internet

Comment: nope I just made it before I play on the same pc .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some of you, like me, may have recently logged in to find that your
>   saved item sets were gone or, even worse, noticed they were gone once
>   you were in game. I thought I had lost my item sets because my son had
>   logged into his account on my pc and set up his own item sets however
>   this may have happened because of a small update that Riot did just
>   recently. Regardless, I did some toying around and got my sets back.
>
> Here is how:
>
> First, exit your LoL client.
>
> Then go to the path
>
> Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/projects/lol_air_client/releases
>
> Here you should see several folders beginning with 0.0.0 open the one
>   named 0.0.1.18 or 16. You may not see 18 or 16 just use the second to
>   last one you have.
>
> Then deploy/preferences
>
> Here you will find a properties file with your account name on it.
>   Ignore all the other files (including the shared_ files) and copy the
>   youraccountname.properties file.
>
> Now, go back three folders (Riot Games/League of
>   Legends/RADS/projects/lol_air_client/releases) and this time, open the
>   latest one which should be named 0.0.1.20
>
> Now click on the deploy folder and then preferences. You will see
>   similar files as before. Paste your properties file here. Your PC will
>   tell you that there is another file with the same name and ask you
>   what you want to do. Select Copy and Replace.
>
> Now start your client back up, enter your account info, and you should
>   see your Item sets back in place.

This is what I found, hope it helps.

Link [here](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3489703).

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as completed if your question has been answered. Thanks.